# socket.io - Same user have multiple sockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io-1.0

I developing an realtime application with node.js and socket.io. My Problem is that I use PHP to login the user. On the connection the user emit the infos to the server. But if the user open an second tab with the same login data. The new tab will not get the **notifications** from the server. Only the old socket.

**`client.js`**:

```
var socket = io('http://192.168.178.165:3000');

socket.on('auth',function () {
    socket.emit('auth resp',{'name':user_name,'id':user_id});
});
```

**`server.js`**:

```
var count = 0;
var users = {};

var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.emit('auth');
    client.on('auth resp',function (data) {
        if(data.id in users) {
            //User has second socket
        } else {
            client.u_name = data.name;
            client.u_id = data.id;
            users[client.u_id] = client;
            count++;
        }
    });
  client.on('disconnect', function(){
    count--;
    delete users[client.u_id];
  });
  client.on('join',function(room){
    client.join(room);
  });
  client.on('leave',function(room){
    client.leave(room);
  });
});
```

Comment: do you use the same room name for the user?

Comment: I only would like to know how I should save the socket. from the same user. Momently I can store only one

Comment: where do you want to store socket ?

Comment: In the `users` array variable